# How do I use :not() to target a general selector with specific parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is an example of what I have

```
var exitLinkSelectors = 'a:not(.external_link)';

$(document).on('click', exitLinkSelectors, function(e){
    // ....
});
```

This targets every anchor except for the ones with external_link class. However what I want is for it also not to target

```
.exclude a
```

I want to write

```
var exitLinkSelectors = 'a:not(.external_link, .exclude a)';
```

But this doesn't work like that, is there a way to write this with :not()? I know I can add a class to the exclude links and target it that way but I would prefer the :not() so it is more dynamic.

http://jsfiddle.net/qDafT/

Comment: As per docs, it should work **All selectors are accepted inside :not(), for example: :not(div a) and :not(div,a).**

Comment: `var exitLinkSelectors = 'a:not(.external_link, .exclude a)';` works for me http://jsfiddle.net/qDafT/1/

Comment: `a:not(.external_link, .exclude a)` should work OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per docs, it should work.

> All selectors are accepted inside :not(), for example: :not(div a) and :not(div,a).

and tried `var exitLinkSelectors = 'a:not(.external_link, .exclude a)';` which worked fine for me **http://jsfiddle.net/qDafT/1/**

Comment: Let me test my actual code again, i tried this before but it didn't work but obviously the fiddle is good

Comment: yea this works, the error was somewhere else I had the selector defined as 'a:not(.external_link, .exclude a), .others' so that format is wrong going to $(document).on('click', exitLinkSelectors, function(e), thanks

Answer (score 0):

Personnally, I would have done the check in the callback, I guess it will be more performant!

```
$(document).on('click', "a", function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.hasClass("external_link") || $this.closest(".exclude").length > 0) 
        return;

    // ....
});
```